# Swift: "Cannot assign value of type 'Item!' to type 'Item!"

Tags: objective-c, swift, casting, variable-assignment

I have a mixed Obj-C - Swift app.
My custom Obj-C `MapViewController` has the following header file, where `Item` is a custom class written in Swift:

```
@class Item;
@interface MapViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) Item *item;
@end
```

The segue to the `MapViewController` is initiated with an `Item` object `item` using

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier(kMapSegueId, sender: item)
```

This calls, where `item` is sent as `sender`:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == kMapSegueId {
        let mapViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! MapViewController
        mapViewController.item = sender as! Item! // This gives the error
    }
}
```

However, the assignment to the property `item` of the `MapViewController` gives the compiler error

**Cannot assign value of type 'Item!' to type 'Item!'**

How can I avoid this strange error?

Comment: The `as!` already unwraps the optional, the exclamation mark after `Item` is meaningless and most likely the issue.

Comment: @vadian: I tried this before, but without the exclamation mark behind Item, I get the error "Cannot assign value of type 'Item' to type 'Item!'"

Comment: Does `Item` have `@objc` attribute?

Comment: @Cy-4AH: No, it hasn't. Where should it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **vadian** and **Rob Napier** suggested, **my code was wrong due to the exclamation mark behind Item**.
However, removing it did give another compiler error. The reason was the following:

When I started to translate my existing Obj-C project to Swift, I set up the Bridging header, and imported there all my h-files, since all my classes were written in Obj-C.  I then started to translate class by class to Swift.
**What I forgot was to remove the #import statement for the files, that were already translated to Swift.** So, there were still import statements for the classes `Item` and `ViewController`.

As soon as I deleted these import statements from the bridging header, the compiler error disappeared.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the extra `!`. You should convert to `Item`, not `Item!`.

```
    mapViewController.item = sender as! Item
```

The compiler is trying to make too many implicit bridges here; it's one bridge too far. Even though I'm betting the type of `.item` is `Item!`, you should ignore that and always it as `Item`. `!` types in Swift 2.2 have a lot of complexity around them (and should be avoided whenever possible) tied to a lot of magic ObjC bridging. This is why they were redesigned in Swift 3.

---

The above is true, but probably not your problem. The problem is that `sender` is itself optional. So you're trying to cast from `AnyObject?` to `Item`. You need to first unwrap `sender` either with `if let` or `!`.

```
    mapViewController.item = sender! as! Item
```

I would probably rewrite this as:

```
if let item = sender as? Item,
    mapViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? MapViewController
    where segue.identifier == kMapSegueId {
    mapViewController.item = item
}
```

Comment: I tried this before, but without the exclamation mark behind Item, I get the error "Cannot assign value of type 'Item' to type 'Item!'"

Comment: Thanks for your suggested code. I tested it, but the assignment still gives the error "Cannot assign value of type 'Item' to type 'Item!'"

Comment: Your answer is right (+1), but it did not solve my problem, since there was one more problem in my project. I will post my answer in a minute.